# Problem to understand "to manage" in a sentence

Tags: meaning

Usually I don't have problems to understand technical English texts, but in that case I don't know what it means:

> Notice that during a license check, your application does not manage
>   any network connections or use any licensing related APIs in the
>   Android platform.

What does "does not manage" mean? Does it mean that I need any network connection or not or does it mean that it cannot handle network connections while license check or maybe something else? I don't understand the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: You mean “have problems understanding”, not “have problems to understand”.  You cannot say “problem to understand” at all.

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of questions than ELU does.

Answer (score 1):

[ODO on *manage*:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manage?q=manage)

> - maintain control over (a person or animal):
>     *she manages horses better than anyone I know*
> - control the use or exploitation of (land):
>     *the forest is managed to achieve maximum growth*

While the licence is being checked, the software does not maintain control of any network connections or use any licensing-related APIs.

[Network management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_management) is quite a large subject, but in this case I guess that the application cannot create or use network connections until its licence status has been verified and accepted.